# Plotting Timeseries Julia

Tags: plot, time-series, julia

I have a problem working with plotting time series in Julia.

I am currently using v. 0.6 and the following minimal example

```
using TimeSeries
using MarketData
plot(ohlcv["Open"])
```

results in the errormessage:

> ArgumentError: Millisecond: 63082540800000 out of range (0:999)

Please help

Thanks a lot!

Comment: (which plot package / backend are you using?)

Comment: I used Plots, but PyPlot is also fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a 0.6-related bug in Plots - it is fixed now, and the code in the original question works again.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug.

For now, you can get a decent plot by converting to Float and treating the Dates as labels though:

```
using TimeSeries, MarketData, PyPlot

O               = ohlcv["Open"];
Timestamps      = [Float64(t) for t in O.timestamp];
Timestamplabels = [string(t)  for t in O.timestamp];

plot(Timestamps, O.values);
xticks(Timestamps[1:div(end,4):end], Timestamplabels[1:div(end,4):end]);
```

[image]

---

<sub>PS. You didn't specify what plot backend you're using, so I assumed PyPlot for this example. Your xtick method may vary for other backends (e.g. xticks! for Plots.jl)</sub>

Comment: @Hamlet My pleasure. When an answer resolves your question / problem, please mark it as accepted so that it's removed from the list of unanswered questions. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

[Temporal](https://github.com/dysonance/Temporal.jl) is another time series package that has plotting functionality. (It integrates with the Plots package using RecipesBase). Some example usage below:

```
using Temporal

X = quandl("CHRIS/CME_CL1")  # get historical crude oil prices
x = X["2015/", :Settle]  # get the settle prices from 2015 onward

using Plots
plotlyjs()
plot(x)

using Indicators
m = mama(x)  # mesa adaptive moving average
plot!(m)
```

[image: Temporal time series plotting example]