# Contour plot Julia

Tags: plot, julia

why does the first version work and the second not?

```
x = -3:0.01:3
y = -3:0.01:3

f(x,y)=pdf(MvNormal(mu, sig), [x,y])

contour(x,y,f)

contour(x,y,pdf(MvNormal(mu, sig), [x,y]))
```

Comment: Forgive me if I am mistaken, but didn't you ask a similar simple plotting related question without a (working!) MWE a couple of hours ago where the answer could just be found by using Google? In my view stackoverflow is not for imediately asking questions when they come up but trying to find a solution on your own first.

Comment: To your question: What is `pdf`? I guess it is from Distributions.jl? Which plotting package are you using? Anyways, compare `typeof(f)` and `typeof(pdf(MvNormal(mu, sig), [x,y]))`.

Comment: Regarding my first comment, I am not referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254765/plotting-timeseries-julia) but one that seems to have been deleted.

Comment: It's because in the first you pass a function, in the second you pass a Vector of values (the second is equivalent to `f = pdf(...` not `f(x,y) = pdf(...`)